# In-App Purchases Restore

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to do in-app purchases and everything works fine except Restore. Below is the code I have written:

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue:SKPaymentQueue!)
{
    for transaction:AnyObject in queue.transactions
    {
        let trans : SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction
        var identifier : NSString = trans.payment.productIdentifier
        println(identifier)
    }
}
```

The problem that I face here is I'm not getting the `purchased identifier` here. I think I have miswritten the code.

Answer (score 1):

Riyazul, you need to look at the original transaction when you are restoring purchases.

The code you should need is:

```
var identifier : NSString = trans.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier
```

Let me know if it's still not working.

Comment: I've tested your code in the sandbox but it didn't return any productIdentifier. I'm making restoration with consumable purchases

Answer (score 1):

Add below two lines of code on your button click action

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

**Edit** - for Swift 3:

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```